# HttpWebRequest throws The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httpwebrequest, soapui, restsharp, digest-authentication

This might be a duplicate question but its quite different than what are those in this forums.

I have an Application which consumes a REST API service given by an external vendor.

> I have been testing this with SoapUI 5.2.1 tool and I can get connected and
>   get data as well,

but when I do the same from my application I have been thrown this error at this point:

```
(HttpWebResponse)request2.GetResponse();
```

What I have done prior to this:

1. Tried in SoapUI 5.2.1 works perfectly **Updated**
2. Tried in browser and works perfectly **Updated**
3. I have intentionally gave a wrong password, then the server responded accordingly giving a 401 Unauthorized error
4. Then gave the actual password then it responds with the above error
5. Fiddler responded 401 Unauthorized when composing a request, which it hits the server and it acted naturally. **Updated**

The Code I am using:

The digest Authenticator class:

```
public class DigestAuthFixer
    {
        private static string _host;
        private static string _user;
        private static string _password;
        private static string _realm;
        private static string _nonce;
        private static string _qop;
        private static string _cnonce;
        private static DateTime _cnonceDate;
        private static int _nc;

        public DigestAuthFixer(string host, string user, string password)
        {
            // TODO: Complete member initialization
            _user = user;
            _password = password;
            _host = host;
        }

        private string CalculateMd5Hash(
            string input)
        {
            var inputBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
            var hash = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(inputBytes);
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var b in hash)
                sb.Append(b.ToString("x2"));
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        private string GrabHeaderVar(
            string varName,
            string header)
        {
            var regHeader = new Regex(string.Format(@"{0}=""([^""]*)""", varName));
            var matchHeader = regHeader.Match(header);
            if (matchHeader.Success)
                return matchHeader.Groups[1].Value;
            throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Header {0} not found", varName));
        }

        public string GetDigestHeader(
            string dir)
        {
            _nc = _nc + 1;

            var ha1 = CalculateMd5Hash(string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", _user, _realm, _password));
            var ha2 = CalculateMd5Hash(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "GET", dir));
            var digestResponse =
                CalculateMd5Hash(string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2:00000000}:{3}:{4}:{5}", ha1, _nonce, _nc, _cnonce, _qop, ha2));

            //return string.Format("Digest username=\"{0}\", realm=\"{1}\", nonce=\"{2}\", uri=\"{3}\", " +
            //    "algorithm=MD5, response=\"{4}\", qop={5}, nc={6:00000000}, cnonce=\"{7}\"",
            //    _user, _realm, _nonce, dir, digestResponse, _qop, _nc, _cnonce);

            return string.Format("Digest username=\"{0}\", realm=\"{1}\", nonce=\"{2}\", uri=\"{3}\", " +
                "response=\"{4}\", qop={5}, nc={6:00000000}, cnonce=\"{7}\"",
                _user, _realm, _nonce, dir, digestResponse, _qop, _nc, _cnonce);
        }

        public string GrabResponse(
            string dir)
        {
            var url = _host + dir.TrimStart('/');
            var uri = new Uri(url);
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);


            // If we've got a recent Auth header, re-use it!
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_cnonce) &&
                DateTime.Now.Subtract(_cnonceDate).TotalHours < 1.0)
            {
                var digestHeader = GetDigestHeader(dir);
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", digestHeader);
            }

            HttpWebResponse response;
            try
            {
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };
                //ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = false;
                //https://holyhoehle.wordpress.com/2010/01/12/webrequest-slow/
                System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null;
                request.Proxy = null;
                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                // Try to fix a 401 exception by adding a Authorization header
                if (ex.Response == null || ((HttpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                    throw;

                var wwwAuthenticateHeader = ex.Response.Headers["WWW-Authenticate"];
                _realm = GrabHeaderVar("realm", wwwAuthenticateHeader);
                _nonce = GrabHeaderVar("nonce", wwwAuthenticateHeader);
                _qop = GrabHeaderVar("qop", wwwAuthenticateHeader);

                _nc = 00000001;
                _cnonce = new Random().Next(123400, 9999999).ToString();
                _cnonceDate = DateTime.Now;

                var request2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
                var digestHeader2 = GetDigestHeader(uri.AbsoluteUri);
                request2.Headers.Add("Authorization", digestHeader2);
                //https://holyhoehle.wordpress.com/2010/01/12/webrequest-slow/
                System.Net.WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null;
                request2.Proxy = null;

                try
                {
                    response = (HttpWebResponse)request2.GetResponse();
                }
                catch (Exception er)
                {

                    throw er;
                }

            }

            var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }

    public class DigestAuthenticator : IAuthenticator
    {
        private readonly string _user;
        private readonly string _pass;
        private readonly string _host;

        public DigestAuthenticator(string user, string pass, string host)
        {
            _user = user;
            _pass = pass;
            _host = host;
        }

        public void Authenticate(IRestClient client, IRestRequest request)
        {
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_user, _pass);

            var url = client.BuildUri(request).ToString();
            var uri = new Uri(url);

            var digestAuthFixer = new DigestAuthFixer(_host, _user, _pass);
            digestAuthFixer.GrabResponse(uri.PathAndQuery);
            var digestHeader = digestAuthFixer.GetDigestHeader(uri.PathAndQuery);
            request.AddParameter("Authorization", digestHeader, ParameterType.HttpHeader);

        }
    }
```

Rest Proxy Class:

```
public class RESTProxy
    {

        string DEFAULT_MODULE = "my-rest";

        string DEFAULT_HOST = "http://xxxx.org/";
        string DEFAULT_USER = "xxx:xxxx:xxx";
        string DEFAULT_PASS = "xxxx";

        public T Execute<T>(RestRequest request) where T : new()
        {
            //@"http://igvde.nrifintech.com:8181/igv-rest-uat"
            var client = new RestClient(string.Concat(DEFAULT_HOST,DEFAULT_MODULE))
            {
                Authenticator = new DigestAuthenticator(DEFAULT_USER, DEFAULT_PASS, DEFAULT_HOST)
            };

            var response = client.Execute<T>(request);

            if (response.ErrorException != null)
            {
                throw response.ErrorException;
            }
            return response.Data;
        }

        public RestRequest initRestRequest(string pRestResourceName, Method pRestServiceVerb, object pRestRequestBody)
        {
            var request = new RestRequest(pRestResourceName, pRestServiceVerb);
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;


            if (pRestRequestBody != null)
            {
                request.AddBody(pRestRequestBody);
            }

            return request;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. This is too much irrelevant code. If a request through Fiddler works and a request through code doesn't, then go and find the differences. Also, a 500 error means that the remote server encountered an error processing your request; it doesn't have to be your code that's wrong.

Comment: If the remote server is returning 500, that means *it*, not your application, is failing. However, 500 is a perfectly valid response. Your application should account for potentially receiving 500 or other similar error codes, and recover gracefully.

Comment: I am sorry for this. This unusual activity happened when my SoapUI tool was working perfect for the same request but the .net frameworks' HttpWebRequest did not. Thats what is the problem. I am sorry again.